# What is the difference between NRDP vs NCPA

Tags: nagios

I am very familiar of using Nagios with NRDP,  NRDP I use for remote server traps handling! but am unable to understand what is NCPA can any one explain me? for what this NCPA is required in actual?

I have seen in below Nagios user agent comparison link that NCPA is the best among the other agents like NRDS,NSClient,NRPE.

Iam unable to understand what is NCPA from below mentioned official definition.

**NRDP**

Nagios Remote Data Processor (NDRP) is a flexible data transport mechanism and processor for Nagios. It is designed with a simple and powerful architecture that allows for it to be easily extended and customized to fit individual users' needs. It uses standard ports protocols (HTTP(S) and XML) and can be implemented as a replacement for NSCA.

**NCPA**

NCPA is a cross-platform monitoring agent that runs on Windows, Linux/Unix, and Mac OS/X machines. Its features include both active and passive checks, remote management, and a local monitoring interface.

Comment: One use case I can remember is NCPA is to do the checks and NRDP is to process the results of NCPA.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare NCPA with NSClient++, they are both agents that can run on servers and actively or passively execute checks through commands over different protocols, scuh as NRPE, NSCA and NRDP.

Agents: NSClient++, NCPA

**Protocols - Active:**

NRPE => https://docs.nsclient.org/reference/windows/NSClientServer/

**Protocols - Passive:**

NSCA => https://docs.nsclient.org/reference/client/NSCAClient/

NRDP => https://docs.nsclient.org/reference/client/NRDPClient/

Fyi, imho NSClient++ is much better then NCPA, as it has amongst other features integrated real-time eventlog monitoring.